# Show the dashboad without any resources

Tags: react-admin

If a user don't have any rights to show resources of react-admin he can not login and he have this message :

```
React-admin is properly configured.
Now you can add a first <Resource> as child of <Admin>
```

How can we show the login page and the dash board with no resources ?

```
const App = ({ classes }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Admin
            locale="fr"
            i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
            customReducers={{ reducer, theme: themeReducer }}
            customRoutes={customRoutes}
            appLayout={MyLayout}
            authProvider={authProvider}
            dashboard={Dashboard}
            loginPage={MyLoginForm}
            dataProvider={dataProvider}
        >
            {permissions => [

                hasRight(permissions, 'resource') ?
                    <Resource name="Myresource"
                        list={MyresourceList}
                        show={hasRight(permissions, 'show') ? MyresourceShow : null}
                        create={hasRight(permissions, 'create') ? MyresourceCreate : null}
                        edit={hasRight(permissions, 'edit') ? MyresourceEdit : null}
                        />
                    : null,

            ]}

        </Admin>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: How can you know that a user can't have access to any resources if the user isn't logged? In order to help you, can you show us some code?

Comment: Well this is the wanted use case, the user enter his credentials in login view. after that we can get the permissions (from the token) and show the resources for this user. but in my case i get the message above when the user has no rights for any resources.

Comment: Ok, seems clear to me! But I'm not sure about the solution. I'll ask to the maintainers and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Any news about this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message should be used to debug only, for sure.
I opened an issue on React Admin: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2749

In the meantime, you can copy the check done in the `authProvider` before rendering the Admin component.

```
const App = () => {
    if (userHasNotAccess) {
        return <ErrorPage />;
    }

    return (
        <Admin {...props}>
            {/* ... */}
        </Admin>
    );
};
```